# Was Marvolo Gaunt's Ring or the Resurrection Stone the Horcrux?

Tags: harry-potter

Was Marvolo Gaunt's Ring or the Resurrection Stone the Horcrux?

I'm asking this because Dumbledore states that he was a fool, sorely tempted, and put on the ring, which sort of implies that he couldn't have taken the Resurrection Stone out of the Ring with a spell or physically, sort of like how you break off pieces of bread or finger food, prior to destroying the Horcrux?

Answer (score 5):

The stone was part of the ring, in the same way that pages were part of the diary.

We know that the locket was hard to damage normally.  As Ginny tried to flush the diary away (rather than tear it up, burn it or otherwise destroy it), we can assume that this is either a *horcrux* trait, rather than being specific to the locket, or a protection that Riddle Jr applied to *all* his (deliberate and/or non-living) horcruxes for protection.

Presumably, this would prevent the stone from being removed from the ring before the protective spells were destroyed.  If the protective spells could only be destroyed by something able to destroy a horcrux - fiendfyre, basilisk venom, et cetera - then you *can't* remove the stone before destroying the horcrux.

Answer (score 2):

Voldemort intended to use the Gaunt Ring as his Horcrux.

> “And Voldemort never knew about the Hallows?”...
> “I do not think so, because he did not recognize the Resurrection Stone he
> turned into a Horcrux."

Also, it is mentioned somewhere in Deathly Hallows (No quote because I didn't have time to comb through the whole book) that Voldemort made Horcruxes from special items. A family ring, passed through the generations, is certainly special enough.

Also highly likely, though this is speculation, that the Gaunts also didn't know of the Stone, perhaps a secret that got lost through time?

So, knowing that Voldemort did not know of the Stone, we can conclude that he intended to use the Gaunt Family ring.